# Printing listview data via wireless printer

Tags: android, listview, android-print-framework

Is that possible to print listview data via wireless printer.

For example, i have data in listview like this,

```
Product - A         3,90

Product - B         2,90

Product - C         4,00

Product - D         5,10

Product - E         0,70

Product - F         3,90
```

I want to print these data to a paper (if possible, with specific format)

Answer (score 2):

On Android 4.4+, you can use Print API.

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

You can print image, web page, PDF file, etc.

Comment: this is not an answer i am looking forward but it works =) Thank you.